# Entity Framework. Query Entitties with Many to Many relation

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities:

```
public class Banner {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
} // Banner

public class Role {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Banner> Banners { get; set; }
} // Role
```

I have a list of roles ids:

```
List<Int32> roles;
```

I need to find all banners that contains at least one of the roles in my list:

```
context.Banners.Where(x => x.Roles.Contains(????))
```

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
context.Banners.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(r => roles.Contains(r.Id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Roles.Where(r => roles.Contains(r.Id)).SelectMany(r=>r.Banners)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to run nested Anys:

```
context.Banners.Where(x => roles.Any(roleId => x.Roles.Any(BannerRole => roleId == BannerRole.Id)
```